# Fourier Transform with condition

Tags: fourier-transform

Imagine a 3D vector field $\vec{E}$ in a specific volume.
There exists a 3D fourier transform with wave numbers $\vec{k} = (k_x, k_y, k_z)$.
Now I want to find a decomposition of the vector field into fourier components satisfying $\vec{E}\cdot\vec{k} = 0$.

Is it possible to find a decomposition with this constraint or does uniqueness of the fourier transform forbid this?

Comment: You're treating $\vec{E}$ as your function that varies in $x,y,z$, correct? So you would be doing the integral $$\int_{\Bbb R^3} e^{-i\vec{r}\cdot\vec{k}} \vec{E}(\vec{r})\,d\vec{r}$$ yes?

Comment: Yes, that is my fourier transform.

Comment: Oh dang that should have been $dV(\vec{r})$. Anyway, I'm not sure that you can do this.